# Como cambiar el valor de una variable antes de ser leída por otra función en caso de que su valor sea undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una función (`insertPicture`) que hace una llamada a una API y devuelve una foto (una url) de una ciudad que ha elegido el usuario. Con la respuesta de esta API asigno la variable `pictureData`

El problema es que a veces esta API no encuentra ninguna foto y entonces la variable `pictureData` se le asigna undefined.

Como luego hay otra función (`addMarkUp`) que usa esta variable `pictureData` cuando la va a usar el programa se rompe al ser pictureData `undefined`. En concreto es cuando la función (`addMarkUp`) va a asignar pictureData al state del componene.

Mi objetivo es que antes de que la segunda función use la variable pictureData, en caso de que sea undefined,  tener una lógica anterior que asigne una dirección url universal (una imagen universal que yo decida) a `pictureData`, de forma que la segunda función nunca se encuentra con un `undefined`

Este es mi código:

```js
addMarkUp = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const pictureData = await this.insertPicture(this.state.new_site);
       
        Geocode.fromAddress(this.state.new_site).then(
      
            response => {
                const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    // Aqui el programa se rompe si pictureData es undefined
                    user_sites: [{
                        "name": this.state.new_site, "id": this.state.user_sites.length + 1, coordinates: [lat, lng], "urlpic": pictureData.photos[0].src["small"]
                    }, ...prevState.user_sites]
                }))
                this.updateDynamo()
            },
            error => { console.error(error); }
        );
    }

async insertPicture(site) {
          return pexelsClient.search(site, 1, 1).catch(function(e) {
          console.err(e);
        });
    }
```

Esto es lo que he probado:

```js
addMarkUp = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        let pictureData = await this.insertPicture(this.state.new_site);
        Geocode.fromAddress(this.state.new_site).then(
            response => {
            if(pictureData === undefined){
          pictureData = "www.urluniversal.com"
        }
                const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    user_sites: [{
                        "name": this.state.new_site, "id": this.state.user_sites.length + 1, coordinates: [lat, lng], "urlpic": pictureData.photos[0].src["small"]
                    }, ...prevState.user_sites]
                }))
                this.updateDynamo()
            },
            error => { console.error(error); }
        );
    }
```

Error:

```
AddSite.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
at AddSite.<anonymous> (AddSite.js:69)
```

La linea 69 es esta:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
                user_sites: [{
                    "name": this.state.new_site, "id": this.state.user_sites.length + 1, coordinates: [lat, lng], "urlpic": pictureData?.photos[0].src["small"] ?? 'url por defecto'

                }, ...prevState.user_sites]
            }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el operador `?` para evitar error  si `pictureData` es undefined y luego usa `??` para retornar la url por defecto.

Reemplaza:

```
pictureData.photos[0].src["small"]
```

por:

```
pictureData.photos[0]?.src["small"] ?? 'url por defecto'
```

Comment: Es verdad no había caído en eso. ¿Sabes dónde podría poner ese código? Porque he probado a ponerlo dentro de la función Geocode.fromAddress y me sigue dando undefined

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, encontré una forma más breve.

Comment: Tambien pensaba asi pero se sigue rompiendo. Sino Voy a intentar poner un repo online de la app

Comment: Agrega el error que te da

Comment: Hecho, lo acabo de añadir

Comment: Entonces photos es el que está undefined. mueve el `?` y colócalo después de photos